# Retrieving Joomla Admin Password does not require salt string?

Tags: authentication, hash, joomla

I was debugging a Joomla site that had it's Super User password forgotten. The solution that I found was logging in to the database and changing the `password` field in the user table to:

```
d2064d358136996bd22421584a7cb33e:trd7TvKHx6dMeoMmBVxYmg0vuXEA4199
```

which is the hash for "secret". So far so good, however, I thought that the hash function takes the password and concatenates it with something else, either the username or a salt string or both and then spits out the hash code. To my surprise the above scenario worked so is it safe to conclude the Joomla only hashes the password itself without adding anything else to it?

Comment: I'm confused, from your description you used the database not Joomla to do the hash. How would Joomla have added the salt in this scenario?

Comment: This is exactly what I'm asking. I could not use Joomla itself to change the password as this is a Super Admin account, the only one created in this case. Thus I went to the database and changed the password field from there which I thought should not work but it did...

Comment: Of course, just login, enter a new password and save. That will save using BCrypt if you are on the current release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you saved directly in the database what happened is that the string was effectively `''` so it's not that there is no salt, it is that the salt is an empty string.  Joomla knows how to handle salts and an empty string is just a special case of a salt, one you should only use temporarily in order to regain access to your site. It's much better to use the root user function since that puts up a big notice reminding you to undo it.

Comment: Isn't the salt string saved somewhere in the code files though? Then every time I log in, it should be added to the password I type in before passing through the hash function. And if that is really the case, then the two hashes would be different and I would not be able to log in? (I haven't changed salt strings anywhere in the code or in the database for the scenario above)

Comment: The salt string is saved with the password.  In your case it is ''. For example in the old salted md5 passwords in Joomla they were concatenated with the password string with a colon as the separator. In the BCrypt hashed passwords they are concatenated with a '.'.

Comment: Interesting, I guess I'm confused with systems where the salt string is saved and configured through the system itself and not saved in the database along with the password in which case the above scenario should not have worked. Thank you very much for the explanation.